# Adding to an ArrayList from another class

Tags: java, class, arraylist, addition

I have two classes. `Museum` and `Painting`.
The `Painting` class is working as expected, but I am having issues with the `Museum` class.
We have been asked to create a method signature that will `addPainting(String, String)` which has two parameters Artist and Location and adds a new `Painting` to the museum paintings collection.

When I try to compile the code, I get no suitable matching methods found?

Does anyone know what I'm missing here?

```java
public class Museum  {
    //creating the fields
    private ArrayList<Painting> paintings;
    private String name;

    /**
     * Create a Museum Class 
     */
    public Museum(String aMuseum) {
        paintings = new ArrayList<>();
        name = aMuseum;
    }

    /**
    * Add a painting from the Paintings class
    */
    public void addPainting(String artist, String location) {
        paintings.add(artist, location);
    }
}
```

Comment: `paintings::add` takes a single argument of type `Painting`, not two arguments of type `String`s.

Comment: You are missing many key concepts, instead of fixing this code right away, I would suggest first read about Generics (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html) and then read about ArrayList

Comment: You want to add a new `Painting`; so, it should be `paintings.add(new Painting(artist, location));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a new `Painting` object, and then add it to the paintings list.

instead of

```
paintings.add(artist, location);
```

you should do something like:

```
Painting p = new Painting(artist, location);
paintings.add(p);
```

Of course, you should also implement the `Painting` constructor (in the `Painting` class).

Comment: Thanks. This allows me to add paintings directly to the Musuem array list. The challenge I am having is when I add a new object to the Paintings class, this should store within the Museum array list. I could be wrong, but I think I need to somehow call on a method from within the Paintings class to retreive this information?

Comment: If you want to use this list from out of the Museum class, you should have a "getter" method, in order you can getPaintings() and iterate the list's objects.